# issues with gem path with travis ci and ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, bundler, travis-ci

I am using travis for the first time and am trying to understand why my bundle installed gems are not available with ruby 1.8.7

*Gemfile*

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rspec'
```

*.travis.yml*

```
language: ruby
script: bundle exec rspec
rvm:
- 1.8.7
- 1.9.3
- 2.0.0
```

*travis output*

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7 --install --binary --fuzzy
Using /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02
$ export BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$PWD/Gemfile
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.25.20 (version) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ gem --version
2.0.14
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.6.1
$ bundle install --deployment
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing diff-lcs 1.2.5
Installing rspec-core 2.14.8
Installing rspec-expectations 2.14.5
Installing rspec-mocks 2.14.6
Installing rspec 2.14.1
Using bundler 1.6.1
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
$ bundle exec rspec
Could not find diff-lcs-1.2.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Comment: Try `bundle exec rspec`?

Comment: updated OP to reflect it a specific issue with ruby 1.8.7

Comment: added gemfile to OP... not much to it ;)

Comment: I am having the same problem with rake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Travis-ci: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2253

There appears to be a workaround, but it haven't tried it.

Comment: added to my travis.yml file `install: ruby -S bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

Based on other references, the suggested .yml file would be:

```
language: ruby
script: "bundle exec rspec"
rvm:
- 1.8.7
- 1.9.3
- 2.0.0
```

Refer to: https://coderwall.com/p/x8exja

Comment: i should have mentioned i had tried that as well with a slightly different issue.. OP updated